# Combined Azure B2C Policy Edit and Password Change

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I was asked if you can have a single B2C policy that does both Profile Edit and Password Change (not SSPR).

My first thought was 'No - do two cards for that' but now that I'm thinking about it - perhaps something in the user journey could handle this

Before I go down this road, if anyone else tried and succeeded (or failed) that would save some cycles. I try to avoid 'recreating the wheel' or 'hitting dead-ends' unnecessarily..

Comment: Technically you could, but I suspect you’d have to force the user to enter the new password every time you ran through the flow. You wouldn’t be able to apply some condition to skip the password entries (the validation technical profile would complain).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement the scenario and I able to do it. Below are the User Journey Code, before that you need to add one claimtype and one technical profile as below.

**Claim type indicates whether user changing the password**

```
<ClaimType Id="isPasswordChangeFlow">
    <DisplayName>Indicates whether user changing the password</DisplayName>
    <DataType>boolean</DataType>
    <AdminHelpText>Add help text here</AdminHelpText>
  </ClaimType>
```

**Technical Profile setting the value of the isPasswordChangeFlow output claim to true**

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="StartPasswordChangeFlow">
      <DisplayName>Change Your Password</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isPasswordChangeFlow" DefaultValue="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

**User Journey**

```
<UserJourney Id="PasswordChangeOrProfileEdit">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
  <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange" >
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
     <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ProfileEdit" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="StartPasswordChangeFlowExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
      <ClaimsExchange Id="ProfileEdit" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="StartPasswordChangeFlowExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="StartPasswordChangeFlow" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>isPasswordChangeFlow</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordChangeExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId1" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

**Make Sure to remove prompt=login parameter from the generated URL to maintain the session.**

Reference [Link](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset)

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Rohit, I was envisioning something a bit different.  We are actually doing what you are describing above already. I am being asked if the UI can have both the edit profile and the change password text fields on a single page and when you click 'submit' B2C figures if you are doing password change, profile edit (or both).

Comment: When I tried this, I get slightly different text on the selection screen. "Sign in" instead of "Choose your option" and "User ID signup" instead of "Edit your profile"... How can I customize the text on the selection screen?